# OSGi declarative service is active, but bind() is not called

Tags: java, linux, osgi, equinox, declarative-services

I'm facing an issue in OSGi context with declarative services which I don't understand. I try to explain:

I have a `FooService` which needs the `FooManagerService (1..1 static)`. The `FooManagerService` references the `FooService`, but it's optional `(0..n dynamic)`.
The goal is, if a `FooService` becomes available, it registers (`bind()` method is called) at the `FooManagerService`, so that the `FooManagerService` always has a list of all available `FooService` implementations in the system.

It works well on Windows, but on Linux I encounter the problem, that the `FooService` becomes active (`activate()` method is called), but that isn't recognized by the `FooManagerService` (`bind()` method isn't called). If I disable and enable `FooService` manually on the OSGi console, it is recognized by the `FooManagerService`.

I don't understand, why this happens. It can be avoided, by increasing the start level of the bundle, where `FooServiceImpl` is located. But that feels like an ugly workaround for, that's why I would like to understand what's going on there.

I attach a picture which describes the references between the services. Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Steffi

[Service Manager Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0urA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cycle here that should be ok according to the theory. However, there are a number of problems in practice.

First, your implementations should be `immediate=true`. This solves some problems since it prevents a nasty problem that DS cannot get a service because it is being initialised. I.e. if the FooManager and the FooService impls must be immediate. This is described in [OSGi enRoute Cycles](http://enroute.osgi.org/appnotes/concurrency.html#cycles)

However, there is one more problem :-( Apache Felix DS has a bug that causes an effect as you describe. This bug is related to bundle ordering. This is reported in [Apache Felix JIRA 5618](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-5618?jql=text%20~%20%22cycle%20ds%22).

If this DS bug is the problem then there is unfortunately only one solid solution. Unfortunate, because it requires you to descent to the bowels of OSGi. The solution is to register the manager service by hand and ensure it is not registered by DS:

```
@Component(service={}, immediate=true )
public class FooManagerImpl implements FooManager {

   private ServiceRegistration<FooManager> registration;

   @Reference
   volatile List<FooService> foos;

   @Activate
   void activate( BundleContext context, Map<String,Object> properties ) {
     registration = context.registerService(FooManager.class, this, new Hashtable<String,Object>(properties));
   }

   @Deactivate
   void deactivate() {
      registration.unregister();
   }

   ...
}
```

The trick here is that the FooManager does not register its service until it has been activated while normally it is registered *before* it is activated.

I know Apache Felix is working on it but do not know how far they are.

Anyway, cycles *always* suck. Sadly, they are not always preventable but I would certainly try.

> Note: registering a service manually will not create a capability. If you use Requirements/Capabilities you should add a service capability in the manifest to make the resolver work. If this line is gibberish to you, ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with immediacy and also for the link to the bugreport.

I'm using the cycle to gain decoupling of components. I have this also on other places, where it never was a problem. But obviously that was only luck until now.
With setting the component of `FooService` to `immediate= true` it works as expected.